# Proving period doubling bifurcation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I am working with a 3D continuous dynamical system. I have plotted the bifurcation diagram and found that period-doubling bifurcation occurs at a certain parameter value. However, I also want to prove it analytically but haven't found any analytical method to do so. Is there any analytical method to prove the existence of period-doubling bifurcation of a 3D continuous system?

Comment: I took out the [periods] tag, since that usually refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(algebraic_geometry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be quite hard to give a purely analytical proof for continuous systems, since period doubling analysis (which is typically via Lyapunov-Schmidt bifurcation theory) will need to be carried on the the Poincare (discrete-time) map of the continuous system, and getting a good analytical handle on Poincare Maps is hard. The closest I could find was:

Period doubling in the Rössler system—a computer assisted proof
D Wilczak, P Zgliczyński - Foundations of Computational Mathematics, 2009.

As the title says, its not 100% analytical but it is rigorous.